# Draw the progress path from right to left in semi circle donut chart using d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I wants to create a semi circle donut chart that showing the percentage of completion. But requirement is to draw the percentage mapping from right to left, not from left to right. The following is my code,

```
var percent = 30;        


    var ratio=percent/100;

    var pie=d3.layout.pie()
            .value(function(d){return d})
            .sort(null);

    var w=300,h=300;

    var outerRadius=(w/2)-10;
    var innerRadius=85;


    var color = ['#ececec','#f06b3e','#888888'];

    var colorOld='#F00';
    var colorNew='#0F0';

    var arc=d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(innerRadius)
            .outerRadius(outerRadius)
            .startAngle(0)
            .endAngle(Math.PI);


    var arcLine=d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(innerRadius)
            .outerRadius(outerRadius)
            .startAngle(0);

    var svg=d3.select("#chart")
            .append("svg")
            .attr({
                width:w,
                height:h,
                class:'shadow'
            }).append('g')
            .attr({
                transform:'translate('+w/2+','+h/2+')'
            });



    var path=svg.append('path')
            .attr({
                d:arc,
                transform:'rotate(-90)'
            }).attr({
                'stroke-width':"1",
                stroke:"#666666"
            })
            .style({
                fill:color[0]
            });


    var pathForeground=svg.append('path')
            .datum({endAngle:0})
            .attr({
                d:arcLine,
                transform:'rotate(-90)'
            })
            .style({
                fill: function (d,i) {
                    return color[1];
                }
            });


    var middleCount=svg.append('text')
            .datum(0)
            .text(function(d){
                return d;
            })
            .attr({
                class:'middleText',
                'text-anchor':'middle',
                dy:0,
                dx:5
            })
            .style({
                fill:d3.rgb('#000000'),
                'font-size':'60px'



            });

    var oldValue=0;
    var arcTween=function(transition, newValue,oldValue) {
        transition.attrTween("d", function (d) {
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, ((Math.PI))*(newValue/100));

            var interpolateCount = d3.interpolate(oldValue, newValue);

            return function (t) {
                d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
                middleCount.text(Math.floor(interpolateCount(t))+'%');
                arcLine=d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(innerRadius)
            .outerRadius(outerRadius)
            .startAngle(function(){
                return (newValue * (Math.PI / 180));
            });
            return arcLine(d);
            };
        });
    };


pathForeground.transition()
        .duration(0)
        .ease('cubic')
        .call(arcTween,percent,oldValue);
```

In the above code we are drawing a semi circle donut chart using svg:path and then again drawing another svg:path for indicating the percentage of completion from left to right.

How can we draw the percentage indicator from right to left instead of left to right using d3js?

Comment: Are you sure this does what you want just backwards right now? Because when I added a duration other than 0 to your transition, the animation is pretty quirky.

https://jsfiddle.net/nph/qn5x9vp0/

Comment: @NathanHinchey My intention was to plot the progress from right end of the half circle to left  based on the percentage value, but didn't worked. I tweaked the startAngle() of the arcLine object in the arcTween from 0 to newValue * (Math.PI / 180) and that is why it executes like this.If I changed this to 0 again the code will work charm. I need the startAngle at 180 degree and plot towards the left. For example if the percentage value that I need to plot is 30, then it should plot 30% starting from 180 degrees of the half circle toward the  left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you got a `rotate(90)` on your arc that was breaking my brain, so I removed it.  Now let's start thinking about where our angles are.  Essentially, you want to animate starting at `Math.PI/2` and go backwards towards 0.  The math then looks like this:

[image]

Here's some running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  Click Chart to Re-Animate!
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <script>
    var percent = Math.random() * 100;

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .value(function(d) {
        return d
      })
      .sort(null);

    var w = 300,
      h = 300;

    var outerRadius = (w / 2) - 10;
    var innerRadius = 85;


    var color = ['#ececec', '#f06b3e', '#888888'];

    var colorOld = '#F00';
    var colorNew = '#0F0';

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .innerRadius(innerRadius)
      .outerRadius(outerRadius)
      .startAngle(0)
      .endAngle(Math.PI);


    var arcLine = d3.svg.arc()
      .innerRadius(innerRadius)
      .outerRadius(outerRadius);

    var svg = d3.select("#chart")
      .append("svg")
      .attr({
        width: w,
        height: h,
        class: 'shadow'
      }).append('g')
      .attr({
        transform: 'translate(' + w / 2 + ',' + h / 2 + ')'
      })
      .on('click', function(){
        pathForeground.transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .ease('cubic')
          .call(arcTween, Math.random() * 100, 0);
      });

    var path = svg.append('path')
      .attr({
        d: arc,
        transform: 'rotate(-90)'
      }).attr({
        'stroke-width': "1",
        stroke: "#666666"
      })
      .style({
        fill: color[0]
      });

    var pathForeground = svg.append('path')
      .datum({
        endAngle: 0
      })
      .style({
        fill: function(d, i) {
          return color[1];
        }
      });

    var middleCount = svg.append('text')
      .datum(0)
      .text(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .attr({
        class: 'middleText',
        'text-anchor': 'middle',
        dy: 0,
        dx: 5
      })
      .style({
        fill: d3.rgb('#000000'),
        'font-size': '60px'
      });

    var oldValue = 0;
    
    var arcTween = function(transition, newValue, oldValue) {
      transition.attrTween("d", function(d) {

        arcLine.startAngle(Math.PI / 2);
        
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(Math.PI / 2, (Math.PI / 2) - (Math.PI * (newValue / 100)));
        var interpolateCount = d3.interpolate(oldValue, newValue);

        return function(t) {
          d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
          middleCount.text(Math.floor(interpolateCount(t)) + '%');
          return arcLine(d);
        };
      });
    };

    pathForeground.transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .ease('cubic')
      .call(arcTween, percent, oldValue);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if we have to show progress from left to right, what changes need to be done?